Error with Latex , using Babel package and Randomizechoices package
I'm using the randomizechoices package to write a test. As shown in the following code.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{exam-randomizechoices}
\renewcommand{\thechoice}{\Alph{choice}}
\setrandomizerseed{2024}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \uplevel{Resuelve todas las preguntas.}
        \question Primera pregunta
        \begin{randomizechoices}
            \choice Opción a
            \choice Opción b
            \CorrectChoice Opción correcta
        \end{randomizechoices}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}

But when I use the babel package in Spanish, I get the following errors.
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.15        \end{randomizechoices}
                             
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Extra \endcsname.
\csgdef ...expandafter \gdef \csname #1\endcsname 
                                                  
l.15        \end{randomizechoices}
                             
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.15        \end{randomizechoices}
                             
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Extra \endcsname.
\csgdef ...expandafter \gdef \csname #1\endcsname 
                                                  
l.15        \end{randomizechoices}
                             
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.15        \end{randomizechoices}
                             
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Extra \endcsname.
\csgdef ...expandafter \gdef \csname #1\endcsname 
                                                  
l.15        \end{randomizechoices}
                             
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.15        \end{randomizechoices}
                             
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Extra \endcsname.
\csgdef ...expandafter \gdef \csname #1\endcsname 
                                                  
l.15        \end{randomizechoices}
                             
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \inaccessible 
                         Opción correcta
l.15        \end{randomizechoices}
                             
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Use of \erc@answer doesn't match its definition.
\\erc@createrandomlist ...use {erc@answer}\unskip 
                                                  }\ifdim \wd 0=0pt\else \Pa...
l.15        \end{randomizechoices}
                             
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

texstudio_JkayLg.tex: error: 15: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{randomizechoices}\
texstudio_JkayLg.tex: error: 15: Extra \endcsname. \end{randomizechoices}\
texstudio_JkayLg.tex: error: 15: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{randomizechoices}\
texstudio_JkayLg.tex: error: 13: Use of \erc@answer doesn't match its definition. \end{randomizechoices}\
texstudio_JkayLg.tex: error: 13: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{randomizechoices}

My question is whether it is possible to make these two work together. If I remove the babel package it works fine, but I would like to be able to use it.

A usual mistake: exam-randomizechoices is trying to create a macro name with \roman instead of \romannumeral. Try with \usepackage[spanish, es-lcroman]{babel}.

@JavierBezos since etex is required these days you could perhaps define \def\es@roman#1{\ifincsname\romannumeral#1\else ... what it is now..\fi} so it works in csnames as it does without babel?

@JavierBezos Thank you for your comment, you hit the target, now it works perfectly, no more errors.

@DavidCarlisle .
